# C# cross-thread SendToBack/BringToFront operations on controls

Tags: c#, controls, z-index, picturebox, multithreading

I am developing a card game. I have represented cards with PictureBox class. I have a game where players put cards one on top of another, one by one. Z-index of all these cards are different and when card is put on top i give it top z-index with this code:

```
PictureBox cardPictureBox = move.Card.CardPictureBox;
if (cardPictureBox.InvokeRequired) 
    cardPictureBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(cardPictureBox.BringToFront));
```

This code works fine and all cards are brought to front when they supposed to. I have a problem when this game ends. That is when I need to put PictureBox objects back to their original place. I put them back but they are now not ordered as I ordered them in Designer. I have to rearrange their z-indexes. I do this with the same code, but in a loop where I do the same thing for every card.

Program doesn't throw an exception but just freezes and that's it!?!?!
Did someone encounter this problem, and does it has an answer?

How can I make a safe cross-thread change of PictureBox z-index without my program freezing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to skip the invoke when you're doing them all in a loop at the end:

```
foreach (CardPictureBox cardPB in Collection) 
{
    cardPB.BringToFront();
}
```